# How to properly load a class which implements a parameterized interface?

Tags: java, reflection

`Class<List>`, `Class<List<?>>` or `Class<List<Anything>` actually refer to the same `Class`.

However if I have

```
class MyClass implements List<SomeClass> {
    // ...
}
```

I could then write

```
Class<? extends List<SomeClass>> myClass = MyClass.class;
```

which would then allow me to write

```
List<SomeClass> myInstance = myClass.newInstance();
```

The trick is that I would like to load this class by reflection using `ClassLoader.loadClass` and still declare `myClass` with the same type. What is the proper/simplest way to do this?

I would like a solution which does not raise compilation warnings and does not require `@SuppressWarnings` (which probably means to have a runtime check of the super type, like a more powerful version of `Class.asSubclass`).

Comment: Possibly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356583/can-i-reflectively-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java

Comment: Indeed it seems to be the same issue… and without a general answer :(

Comment: so you have this kind of a requirement just because you don't like suppressing warnings, or you need a bullet-proof type checking?

Comment: The warnings are there for a reason (here it would require unchecked casts), so my question is how to suppress them (which would logically require a runtime check)

Answer (score 2):

```
 public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException
```

As It returns `Class<?>`  Generic class, `your type information is lost here`. So You will have to typecast to desired type.

Comment: As I said in my comment below, the type information is still there. It just seems difficult to check it at runtime, and to avoid warnings. Normally you can avoid the typecast by using `Class.asSubclass` (which also performs a runtime check) but it does not work well with generics.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a class with generic signature, all the information about generics is lost. For jvm, it just as good as:

```
class MyClass implements List {
    // ...
}
```

You can check this if you decompile a class with `javap`: you'll see no generic stuff there. Generics are mostly used for compile time checks. So when you load a class with reflection, you'll have to cast it to your generic version.

Comment: This is a false belief, only a part of the generic info is lost but everything required to compile dependent classes is kept. If you use `MyClass.class.getGenericInterfaces()` you will be able to see the full `List<SomeClass>`.

Comment: @DidierL: oh, sorry, I didn't know about those methods.