# Java Reflect Generic Class DAO Type

Tags: java, reflection

I want to access the Class Type name in order to specify the runtime type. For example

```
DAO<?> i  = DAO<?> DOA.class.forName(”Student”).newInstance();
```

What I am trying to do is I have a class called Student and at runtime I want to specify DAO. When running the code I get a ClassCastException.

Is there any way of getting the Student type instead of String so that the following can be done

```
DAO<?> = new DAO<Student>();
```

by specifying ?

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/75175/130224 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/356583/130224.

Comment: This question is different. My question asks whether it is possible to instantiate a unknown type. So DAO<Student> i = new DAO<Student>() but I want it generic so that DAO<?> i = new DAO<?>(); I want unknown type to be filled in at runtime.

Comment: No, the type argument of DAO is not available at run-time due to type erasure.