# How to type cast programmatically initialized class

Tags: java

I'm trying to programmatically initialize a class and add it to a list.  I don't know how to type `workflowClass` so that it `extends BaseWorkflow` so the list will accept it.  Currently it says I can't add an `Object` when it's expecting `? extends BaseWorkflow`.

```
private static List<? extends BaseWorkflow> workflowList = new ArrayList<BaseWorkflow>();

/**
 * Initialize the production line
 */
public static void init() {
    //load active workflows into memory
    WorkflowService workflowService = (WorkflowService) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("workflowService");
    for (Workflow workflow: workflowService.findActive()) {
        try {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(workflow.getClassName());
            Object workflowClass = clazz.newInstance();
            workflowList.add(workflowClass);
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to add anything to a `List<? extends BaseWorkflow>`. The list should be declared as `List<BaseWorkflow>`. Indeed, `List<? extends BaseWorkflow>` means: *a list of some unknow type which is or extends BaseWorkflow*. Since the type is unknown, adding anything (other than null) to this list would break its type safety.

And then a simple cast will do:

```
workflowList.add((BaseWorkflow) workflowClass);
```

Comment: The class I need in the list though is not `BaseWorkflow`, I need the typed version of `BaseWorkflow`, which is available via `workflow.getClassName()`

Comment: An object has a type, and adding it to a list won't change it. Assuming the class name is `Foo`, the type of the added object will be `Foo`. A Car is a Vehicle. Adding a Car to a list of vehicles doesn't change it to something else. It's still a Car.

Comment: But if I understand correctly (which I probably don't) if it's cast to `Vehicle` and not `Car` then that's not right?

Comment: Casting doesn't change the type of an object. It simply allows getting a a more specific type reference to this object. If you cast a Car to Vehicle, is stays a Car. But since you now have a variable of type Vehicle (instead of Object) to reference this car, you can call Vehicle-specific methods on this object.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast Object explicitly:

```
workflowList.add((BaseWorkflow) workflowClass)
```