# Creating a class and creating an instance from a string

Tags: java

I have a problem in creating an object.

Basically I would like to create an object from a given class by taking originally a string. I know that using `Class.forName(field)` works, but not in my case and I will show you why below. I have thought about reflection but fear it will cause the same problem.

My code as of right now is (template is a String):

```
int n = template.length();
String field = at.getFieldName().trim();
field = field.substring(0, field.length() - 1); 
Class<?> correctClass = Class.forName(field);
UniqueEntity<correctClass> ue = new UniqueEntity<correctClass>();
```

The error message I get is that `correctClass` cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: `correctClass` is a variable - not a type!

Comment: I figured that out, but do you have any idea of a workaround?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356583/can-i-reflectively-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Once you used `Class.forName()` method you got your `Class` instance (variable `correctClass`) invoke method `getConstructor()` or `getConstructors()` to get an instance of class `Constructor`. Once you get your instance of class `Constructor` invoke method `newInstance()` to get an instance of your class. Here is the example:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName(field);
Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor()
Object o = constructor.newInstance()
```

All this assuming that your class has default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to be able to create a `UniqueEntity` with the type of your reflective class, you need to pass the class type into a generic helper method.

```
private static <T> UniqueEntity<T> createEntity(Class<T> clazz) {
    return new UniqueEntity<T>(clazz);
}
```

## Code

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class Generic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String field = "java.lang.Integer";
            UniqueEntity<?> entity = fromField(field);

            System.out.println(entity);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static UniqueEntity<?> fromField(String field) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return createEntity(Class.forName(field));
    }

    private static <T> UniqueEntity<T> createEntity(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new UniqueEntity<T>(clazz);
    }

    private static class UniqueEntity<T> {
        private final Type type;

        public UniqueEntity(Class<T> clazz) {
            this.type = clazz.getGenericSuperclass();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "UniqueEntity [type=" + type + "]";
        }
    }
}
```