# Instantiate a generic class with reflections

Tags: java, generics

I try to create something like an object mapper. For this, I need to instantiate classes at runtime. This is quite easy with 'normal' classes, however, I also have generic classes like Terminal which I need to instantiate at runtime:

```
public class Terminal<T extends ConductingEquipment> extends ACDCTerminal {
  private T conductingEquipment;
  ...
}
```

When I read the document, which I try to map to an object, I know the class/type for T. I try to achieve at runtime something like the following where `ACLineSegment` is just an example and could be one of 38 classes (in the moment):

```
Terminal<ACLineSegment> terminal = new Terminal<>();
terminal.setConductingEquipment(new ACLineSegment());
```

Is it possible to do something similar with reflections without knowing that T should be `ACLineSegment` in beforehand? At the moment I only can instantiate the Terminal without the Type Parameter:

```
terminalClass.newInstance();
```

**UPDATE:**
To specify the difference between my post and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356583/can-i-reflectively-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-java): Is it possible to instantiate a generic class with reflections *without* previously implementing all possible classes. (And how.)

Comment: Everything between the angle brackets is lost and irrelevant at runtime. The instance you create with `terminalClass.newInstance()` is bit-by-bit exactly the same as the one created by `new Terminal<ACLineSegment>()`. Only the compiler doesn't know about the `ACLineSegment` parameter, so he'll give you some warnings later.

Comment: With Java 8, use `Supplier` instead of `Class`. Then, you don’t have to suffer from the drawbacks of Reflection at all. E.g. `Supplier<Terminal<ACLineSegment>> supp = Terminal::new; Terminal<ACLineSegment> terminal1 = supp.get(), terminal2 = supp.get();`

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers. @RalfKleberhoff does this mean when using reflections I don't have to have a parameter in the diamonds operator? Is it then later possible to use `conductingEquipment instanceof ACLineSegment`? @holger I think this solution would work. However, I would need to make a supplier for each possible class (as written in the question for the `Terminal` 38)

Comment: @Daniel With reflection, you don't need the diamonds operator, but you can use it with the class. You'd typically declare `Class<T extends Terminal> terminalClass`. Then `terminalClass.newInstance()` at least knows that the result is (a subclass of) a Terminal. And yes, `conductingEquipment instanceof ACLineSegment` will perfectly work.